# Elevating Privilages to Execute C# code (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: c#, iis-8

I have a IIS8 (server2012) C# code in one of our website scripts which needs to execute firewall update through **(INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID ("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2")**. However it is failing with the **Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)**.

I tried to search for a solution (most of the responses relate to Application Identity Pool and Admin rights change, similar post here: [Acces denied error when I use firewall.dll propertry . (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954548/acces-denied-error-when-i-use-firewall-dll-propertry-exception-from-hresult)) but end up more confused then when I started.

Is there an easy explanation I can follow to allow this one script to run with elevated privileges without granting it to the whole application?

Comment: I don't know how much freedom you have witht your project but in this case i think i'd create a service running with administrative privileges and listening only on localhost/named pipe, when your script want to update the firewall, it will connect to the service which will then perform the operation.

Comment: Is this an internet facing app?

Comment: @Sidewinder94 - just what I was about to suggest as well :)

Comment: @Kev, jes it is internet facing but the actual .aspx file is access restricted so it should never be called externally.

Comment: @Sidewinder94 - That would be a solution but before I go the the extra lengths to create the service and rewrite what we already have I'd like to know if there is a more straight forward solution. Thx.

Comment: OK, ...so I wrote a simple .exe to execute the firewall update and calling it from the original .aspx file with ServiceController service = new ServiceController. If this works, I'll mark Sidewinder94 suggestion as valid. Thx.

Comment: @Sidewinder94 : So I rewrote the service again to run all the time and to listen on specified internal port for any new information. When info comes in, the firewall is updated. Since the service is ran with admin privileges it completely took care of any compromise on the IIS site which can stay under the unprivileged IUSR. Thx for the hint.